# probability of tennis match result, given historic data

Tags: probability

I have previous results of alot of tennis matches and the win probability (for player A) for winning each match. is there a mathematical way for me to calculate the probability of a new result  given a win probability for a player ?

I was thinking that the easiest solution could be to put the win probability in bins, assume I have enough results for it to count as a standard distribution, and then give the probability depending on the results in each bin. But this is not a good mathematical way to do this. is there an alternative?

Comment: What do you mean by "the win probability for each match" Each match has to be won by someone !

Comment: What properties do you want your probability to have?  If $A$ and $B$ have played each other lots of times, you could use their history to get a probability.  Otherwise?  There are things you could make up, but it's hard to have much faith in them.  Predicting the outcome of sporting events is hard!

Comment: I just have the average odds that player A wins. I do not have who has played whom. I think i just dont have enough information. and I have historic data so the previous odds and results from them.